# Make a PictureBox transparent and allow it to be moved

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, picturebox

I would need a picturebox that contains a graphic for an actor. The actor is placed on PictureBoxes that contain a tileset graphic. The actor should be able to move freely which i already did, but the transparent .PNG Actor-Image has a control-colored background when I load it into the form.

**Question:**
How could I make the background of this Image transparent AND allow to be moved?

Comment: Why don't you believe [what you are told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038316/tilesets-and-sprites-in-winforms)? And if you don't understand it, why not ask instead of creating another question with the old problem unfixed. Yes, I basically told you that you __have to thow away the PicurreBox array as it can't work__ I understand you don't like this but that won't change the reality. Believe me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `windowsforms` is that its control does not have **true transparency**

The transparency of a control is based on the `BackgroundColor` or `BackgroundImage` of its parent and that is why your `PictureBox` is Control-Colored

Now if you want to make it true transparency you have some options

### Draw everything yourself

You can use the power of `gdi+` or `Graphics` to draw everything, but only the needed ones

## Handle the draw of the control

This could be a tricky one, you can override the method `OnPaint` and `OnPaintBackground` of the picture box so it do not redraw its background (Control-Colored), the bad side of this is that it will have a lot of flickering and buggy background on movement

## Use another techology

I'm not sure but if I'm not mistaken you could use wpf for this, altough it could change your entire project